# Delete space between first two initials of the name and delete comma after journal name

Tags: bibtex

I want to create a `.bst` file for the *Journal of Molecular Liquids*. I am getting this kind of citation:

> N. F. Dupuis, C. Wu, J.-E. Shea, M. T. Bowers, The amyloid formation
>   mechanism in human iapp: Dimers have -strand monomermonomer inter-
>   faces, J. Am. Chem. Soc., 133 (2011) 7240–7243, doi:10.1021/ja1081537.

But I want this kind of citation

> N.F. Dupuis, C. Wu, J.-E. Shea, M.T. Bowers, The amyloid formation
>   mechanism in human iapp: Dimers have -strand monomermonomer inter-
>   faces, J. Am. Chem. Soc. 133 (2011) 7240–7243, doi:10.1021/ja1081537.

Here is the bib files

```
@article{doi:10.1021/ja1081537,
author = {Dupuis, Nicholas F. and Wu, Chun and Shea, Joan-Emma and Bowers, Michael T.},
title = {The Amyloid Formation Mechanism in Human IAPP: Dimers Have β-Strand Monomer−Monomer Interfaces},
journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
volume = {133},
number = {19},
pages = {7240-7243},
year = {2011},
doi = {10.1021/ja1081537},

URL = {
        https://doi.org/10.1021/ja1081537

},
eprint = {
        https://doi.org/10.1021/ja1081537

}

}
```

I am unable to load the `.bst` file due to its has more than 30000 character.

Comment: You can upload your `.bst` file to a text sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/. Without the `.bst` it is going to be quite hard to tell you what *you* need to change in the `.bst` file.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165222/bibtex-how-to-get-rid-of-a-period-after-author-initial?r=SearchResults&s=1|56.8532 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122334/how-to-remove-a-period-from-middle-initial-in-bst-file-while-leaving-first-name?r=SearchResults&s=2|54.2464

Comment: Here is .bst file https://pastebin.com/P5x1FsGh